# How to install ps in redhat ubi8/ubi-minimal

Tags: redhat, redhat-containers, procps

For `registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal` this image, i need `ps` utility to be installed. There is no `yum` package manager available in the image. Instead , we have `microdnf`.

`microdnf install procps` says there is no such package named `procps`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In the Dockerfile, add the following statement and you should be able to use `ps`

```
 RUN microdnf update && microdnf install procps
```

Comment: The baggage this package brings with it, is surprising.  I simply refuse to believe that "ps" requires "cpio", "cracklib", "systemd" and others.

Comment: Upvoted for the info for using ```RUN microdnf update && microdnf install``` due to the absence of yum package management

Answer (score 7):

The package name is procps-ng

In ubi8/ubi: `yum install procps-ng` results in downloading one package, 389kB.

Similarly for ubi8/ubi-minimal: `microdnf install procps-ng`